# Simplification of recursive polynomials

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, polynomials, recurrence-relations, products

Suppose I have known polynomials $p_i, i=0\ldots k-1$.  I have the following horrific looking recursive equation:
$$p_{k}(x)=-\prod_{i=1}^{k}{(x+i)}^{\left\lfloor\frac{k}{i}\right\rfloor-1}\left[p_o(x)+\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\prod_{i=1}^{j}\left(\frac{x+k+1-i}{(x+i)^{\left\lfloor\frac{j}{i}\right\rfloor}}\right) p_j(x)\right]$$
$$p_{k}(x)=-\prod_{i=1}^{k}{(x+i)}^{\left\lfloor\frac{k}{i}\right\rfloor-1}\left[p_o(x)+\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\left(\frac{\prod_{i=1}^{j}(x+k+1-i)}{\prod_{i=1}^{j}(x+i)^{\left\lfloor\frac{j}{i}\right\rfloor}}\right)p_j(x)\right]$$

This looks crazy.  Is there any way to modify this kind of expression to get something more "usable"?

This arises out of the study of [hypergeometric Bernoulli numbers](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0022314X10001447/1-s2.0-S0022314X10001447-main.pdf?_tid=b1e2679c-9da2-11e4-bf17-00000aab0f02&acdnat=1421428462_f21b8c66b227b643e5f98fc1d8a54f48) where

$$\frac{x^N/N!}{e^x-1-x-\cdots.-(x^{N-1}/(N-1)!)}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{B_k(N)}{k!}x^k$$ and where the $B_k(N)$ are the hypergeometric Bernoulli numbers.  If $N=1$, these are the 1st order Bernoulli numbers, $B_0=1, B_1=-1/2, B_2=1/6,$ etc...

It appears that the numbers have a particular structure, namely

$$B_k(N)=\frac{k!p_k(N)}{\prod_{j=1}^{k}(N+i)^{\left\lfloor\frac{k}{i}\right\rfloor}}$$

The first few $p_k$ are
$$p_0=1 \text{ (trivially) }$$
$$p_1=-1$$
$$p_2=1$$
$$p_3=x-1$$
$$p_4=x^3-x^2-6x+2$$
$$p_5=x^4-4x^3-11x^2+16x-2$$

NOTE:  It appears that $p_{2m+1}(x)=(x-1)q(x)$ for some $q\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$.  This makes sense since the odd indexed Bernoulli number of order 1 are zero.

$$B_{2k+1}(1)=\frac{(2k+1)!p_{2k+1}(1)}{\prod_{i=1}^{2k+1}{(1+i)^{\left\lfloor\frac{2k+1}{i}\right\rfloor}}}=\frac{(2k+1)!(1-1)q_{2k+1}(1)}{\prod_{i=1}^{2k+1}{(1+i)^{\left\lfloor\frac{2k+1}{i}\right\rfloor}}}=0$$

I checked mathematica for the first few and got aforementioned results.

$$p_5=(x-1)(x^3-3x^2-14x+2)$$

$$p_7=(x-1)(x^7-7x^6-81x^5-37x^4+766x^3+1048x^2-390x+12)$$

Comment: Can you provide some context?  Where does this arise?  What are you trying to use it for?

Comment: See my edits above

Comment: Something's off. How could $p_1$ be $-1$?  I get $p_1 = 1$, $p_2 = 2 x + 3$, $p_3 = 4 x^2 + 15 x + 13$, ...

Comment: Yes, something is off...let me check my formula...

Comment: Naturally, i missed a negative.  The whole expression is negative on the RHS.  It may also have to be said for the formula that $k\ge 2$ since if $k=1$, the summation in the brackets goes from 1 to 0...

Comment: $(-1)^k p_k(0)$ seems to be OEIS sequence A092144.

Comment: I would certainly be more interested in those cases where $n\neq 0$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael, I really don't understand where the sequence A092144 comes from...there is not much listed there and I can't find anything in any of the linked sequences either.

Comment: Is any of the stuff in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1408.3708v2.pdf) useful?

Comment: I've seen a lot of that stuff.  Professor Hassen from the bibliography #'s 15-17 is my professor I'm working with.